# java.lang.IllegalStateException:android.os.DeadObjectException

Tags: android

I found a crash in googlePlay Statistics. The frequency is high，and most of them happened at Android N+, but i can't recurrent and don't know why it happened. If you have a solution to the experience， please help.This is the stack information:

```
    threadName:main,threadPriority:5,threadState:RUNNABLE
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy0.activityStopped(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3450)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.limpoxe.fairy.core.g.b.invoke(SourceFile:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
    at $Proxy0.activityStopped(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3450)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:506)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.limpoxe.fairy.core.g.b.invoke(SourceFile:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
    at $Proxy0.activityStopped(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3450)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```